# What does nore mean when mapping keys in vim?

Tags: vim

What does `nore` mean when mapping keys in vim?  For example, what is the difference between these two mappings?

```
:map ddd ddjdd
```

and

```
:noremap ddd ddjdd
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: I tried finding the relevant documentation.  Unfortunately, it's under `recursive_mapping` rather than `nore` or `noremap`, which isn't helpful when you don't know what it means.  I found the answer while reading Learn Vimscript the Hard Way: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html#recursion

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It means the mapping is **no** n - **re** cursive.

To illustrate,

```
:nmap x dd
```

say you map `x` in normal mode to `dd` (delete line), to save up some time in well, deleting lines. Everything works fine, until you need the x (delete character) in some other mapping to delete two characters,

```
:nmap c xx
```

because now the upper mapping is really

```
:nmap c dddd
```

i.e. will delete two lines.

So, to preserve the "original" mappings (vim keys), you do it the non-recursive way,

```
:nnoremap x dd
:nnoremap c xx
```

and everything works (the mappings do not ... ah, you get the idea) ...

It is generally a good practice to do all your mapping with "nore", because you never know what plugins may be relying on what, and what vim behaviour you're breaking with "ordinary" mappings.

Answer (score 3):

It's all covered in the built-in documentation

`map`:

> Map the key sequence {lhs} to {rhs} for the modes
>               where the map command applies.  The result, including
>               {rhs}, is then further scanned for mappings.  This
>               allows for nested and recursive use of mappings.

And `noremap`:

> Map the key sequence {lhs} to {rhs} for the modes
>               where the map command applies.  Disallow mapping of
>               {rhs}, to avoid nested and recursive mappings.  Often
>               used to redefine a command.  {not in Vi}

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Chris.  I always missed those paragraphs.  After searching for `:help noremap`, I never read down the page to the important parts (http://bit.ly/I6THzx), and would jump to the `mapmode-nvo` topic.

Answer (score 1):

`nore` stands for non-recursive.  It causes the right hand side of the mapping to ignore mappings.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was `vi` that made such a counter intuitive setting, which makes `map` stand for recursive map, instead of explictly adding `re` to inply recursive map

https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html

> When should you use these nonrecursive variants instead of their
> normal counterparts?
>
> Always.
>
> No, seriously, always.
>
> Using a bare *map is just asking for pain down the road when you
> install a plugin or add a new custom mapping.

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you read the whole word. "noremap", as in "no re-map". Meaning that the mapping can't be changed.

Comment: When I read it as "no re-map", I think that means that the left hand side can't be changed (re-mapped), rather than meaning that the right hand side can't be affected by other mappings.